# How to create not editable folder structure with editable end folders?

Tags: permissions, 2016, inheritance, subfolders

I got a request to create a quite complex folder tree in Sharepoint 2016. The users shoudn't be able to change the structure, but they have to be able to work in the end folders. For example: "Company => Projects => Marketing => Austria => 2018". The users must not be able to change Company, Projects, Marketing, Austria folder, but they have to be able to create a new folder "2019" inside Austria and add documents to the 2018/2019 folder. Is that possible to archive?
I tried to change the permissions one by one, by stopping the permission inheritance, but still if I change a permission for a group in any folder, it is also change in all other children or parent folder.
Thanks you very much for any advices!

Comment: I'm interested too. For the same task I wrote PWS-script that creates folders and breaks inheritance for the end ones.